# Weird DNS (?) behavior with brand new Windows 10 Laptop: bing/google loads, but no websites

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns

**Hardware**: Surface Laptop 3 13"
**Software**: Windows 10 20H2, all latest updates installed

**Problem**: it seems like there is something broken with the DNS resolution. In both Chrome and Edge (latest versions) bing.com or google.com (and auto completion) work fine. Results are found for any search incl. ads. However, every website that I try to open is not reachable when connected to the home WiFi.
When connected to a mobile hotspot (iPhone) via WLAN, the DNS works. As soon a website was loaded via Hotspot, it will start working on WiFi as well.

**Things that did not solve the issue:**

- Updating all drivers/windows updates
- Using chrome/edge
- Using wired connection to the same network
- Reseting all network settings
- Setting a manual DNS server (8.8.8.8)!
- Following all guides in the internet that I found so far
- A dozen different clients work on the same network (Windows 10, iOS, Android)
- The laptop is brand new, out of the box. Just installed all updates.
- Issue occured with Windows 1909 and 20H2

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your router's DNS settings and [if applicable] any DNS adblocking software it may be running, as that's where the problem is

Comment: Also contact Microsoft Support.  They can access the computer (you approve that) and they can determine the issue.

Comment: @JW0914: Default ISP Router with no special settings. If it were the router, the custom DNS should have helped (and the other clients would be affected I guess).

Comment: @John: Seems like this is not availble at my location (germany)?

Comment: That does present a bit of a problem. There are global support numbers on this page:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/global-customer-service-phone-numbers-c0389ade-5640-e588-8b0e-28de8afeb3f2

Comment: @SurfaceDNS If the issue only occurs while connected to the router's WiFi, the router's DNS/DHCP server, adblocking, or firewall is the issue, as this is an either/or equation: Either the Surface has incorrect manually applied DNS/DHCP adapter settings or it's the router either serving incorrect DNS/DHCP or blocking traffic via its firewall/adblocking software. It's possible Windows' firewall or `hosts` file is blocking the traffic, but this would need to be manually done, which rules it out.

Comment: @John: Seems like I need a windows account with some sort of support plan for Germany (or I am just confused). Will give it a shot though.

Comment: @JW0914: I am guessing it might be the Surface's incorrect DNS/DHCP behavior, however I reset all of that. Also checked the hosts file and disabled Windows' firewall...

Comment: Microsoft Accounts are good and very safe on individual computers. I use a Microsoft Account here - no issues.

Comment: Just a small update: I completly set the hardware back to stock 20H2 windows. And found another WiFi where the same error shows up. I think I give up and will replace the hardware...